# Correct note frequency for STM32 based MIDI synth

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, frequency, synthesizer

I have been playing about with the EasyMXPro for STM32 dev. board from Microelektronica. I am trying to create a simple monophonic wavetable synth using the DAC, playable via. a MIDI keyboard, however, I have the following problems:

I have a loop that cycles through the wavetable values (at the speed of the MCU clock). The rate at which the program cycles through the array obviously gives me an incorrect frequency to that of the fundamental frequency of the sine wave in the wavetable. What is the best way to delay/speed up the execution of the program for each sample in the array, given that I need to cycle through the array at different rates for different notes on the keyboard? I have tried using a simple delay, however for each change in note frequency, the delay amount has to change specifically. Is there an easier way to do this that I have not thought about (perhaps using timers)?

Thanks in advance for any helpful answers!

Answer (score 5):

Most *practical* table based synthesizers use a *fixed* playback sample rate, and a *fractional* phase increment and accumulator register.

Essentially, calculate the phase increment per sample period for your desired output frequency, and pre-multiply by a large power of two, say 1024 or even higher - with an ARM MCU you might as well just multiply it by 2^16.

Each cycle add this phase increment to an accumulator register.

The accumulator will be wider (have more precision) than the address input into your wave lookup table, so simply ignore the lower bits and use only as many upper bits as your lookup table has address bits.  So you might be calculating time with 32-bit accuracy, but only using the upper 16 bits to look up samples in a 65536 element table.

The result is that while the index time of a given sample is *approximate*, the *cumulative* time has many bits of accuracy.  This easily gets you sub-Hz resolution, without the need to alter a timer or DAC clock at all.  And that's important, because typically the cleanup circuitry in a DAC and following its output is designed for only a small number of sample rate(s).

Note that if your lookup table contains a sine or other waveform with symmetry, you can probably shrink its size - for a sine you really only need to store a quarter of a wave, as you can get the other three quadrants by inverting phase or amplitude.

Although the question specifically states monophonic output, this technique is extensible to polyphonic outputs.  A modern processor will have little trouble performing a fair number of such lookups and summing them to feed to the DAC at typical audio sample rates.

Comment: This is also known as "[direct digital synthesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesizer)"

Comment: Even a 2.5MHz Z-80 can handle 4 voice wavetable synthesis (albeit only 8 bit) at 9 kHz sample rate...

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have tried to implement this method using the code found at the following link as a template: link The problem I have is that I'm using the MCU at 16Mhz, however, when I use 16Mhz in the equation in the link (to determine a step size) I obtain just under half the desired frequency output. Using 8Mhz I get a closer output value, but still not a precise one. Is there a problem with this equation or is the problem more likely to be with the clock value I am using?

Comment: The whole point of a DDS is that the output frequency is independent of the clock frequency, and not rounded to some fraction thereof.  If that isn't working, there's a mistake in the implementation.