# Sinusoidal wave output from a GPIO

Tags: stm32, gpio, sine

I think the question is not particularly MCU/board specified but I will be trying it on STM32F4-DISC board.

I was thinking of how to output a nice sinewave from a normal GPIO output pin, but I was not able to find a proper methodology. I am asking for a method of thinking, a guide rather than the complete solution.

Just give me an overview of the process.

If possible of course.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with just a GPIO pin, unless you have a DAC on your MCU (not sure if the STM32 does). When you say "sine wave" do you mean +/- voltage, or 0/+ voltage?

Comment: @RonBeyer hey, I mean a real sinewave, for example peaks at -1 and 1 with some frequency. MCU has DAC. Of course it olny can be an approximation to a real sine wave, I know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only dedicated DAC outputs could do this *directly* but for many purposes you could use a timer output pin in compare mode to generate pulse width modulation (PWM) and vary that in a sinusoidal fashion.  If the you then filter it (sometimes with nothing more than some series resistance and capacitance to ground) you can end up with a reasonable approximation to a sine wave for many purposes.

The greater the difference in frequency between the PWM repetition rate, and the desired sine wave frequency, the better the result you can achieve.

With either a DAC or PWM, you probably want to implement a Direct Digital Synthesizer to produce the amplitude values, at least if you need to vary the frequency or it is not a nice fraction of an available clock.  The DDS algorithm is described in [this existing EESE answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/330177/2246) (describing an audio application, but the technique is general)

> Most practical table based synthesizers use a fixed playback sample
>   rate, and a fractional phase increment and accumulator register.
>
> Essentially, calculate the phase increment per sample period for your
>   desired output frequency, and pre-multiply by a large power of two,
>   say 1024 or even higher - with an ARM MCU you might as well just
>   multiply it by 2^16.
>
> Each cycle add this phase increment to an accumulator register.
>
> The accumulator will be wider (have more precision) than the address
>   input into your wave lookup table, so simply ignore the lower bits and
>   use only as many upper bits as your lookup table has address bits. So
>   you might be calculating time with 32-bit accuracy, but only using the
>   upper 16 bits to look up samples in a 65536 element table.
>
> The result is that while the index time of a given sample is
>   approximate, the cumulative time has many bits of accuracy. This
>   easily gets you sub-Hz resolution, without the need to alter a timer
>   or DAC clock at all. And that's important, because typically the
>   cleanup circuitry in a DAC and following its output is designed for
>   only a small number of sample rate(s).
>
> Note that if your lookup table contains a sine or other waveform with
>   symmetry, you can probably shrink its size - for a sine you really
>   only need to store a quarter of a wave, as you can get the other three
>   quadrants by inverting phase or amplitude.

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer, I will inspect this in detail. I may ask you again from here if I could not understand some aspects.

Answer (score 1):

You would

1. create one cycle of appropriate analog values in a buffer
2. use the values in the buffer to adjust the duty cycle on a PWM output on a GPIO, stepping through the buffer
3. filter the PWM signal with an RC circuit

Of course, "nice" can mean a lot of things.  For the highest quality, use a fast PWM carrier freq, and make sure your buffer makes use of the full resolution of the PWM duty cycle control.

STM32F4's tend to have Digital to Analog converters, which can do the job directly.

You might find http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spraa88a/spraa88a.pdf of use

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I guess not covering anything about DAC results in having no idea on how to do it. I will consider your answer and work on it. But actually I want to ask you something, for example does a %50 duty cycle directly means a nearly 3.3/2 V output? If it is, then by doing duty cycle changes I should be able to see an approximated sine wave on an oscillator screen right?

Comment: Yup, you have it right.  If you need the sinusoid to be centered around 0V, you would need to AC couple it.

Comment: This is because MCU cannot give a negative output right? Is this AC coupling thing is something related to electronics rather than spesificaly MCU? I should do it in somewhere out of the MCU with the help of some kind of circuitry right? I will also check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only pins capable for that on STM32F4 would be the DAC output pins.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will have a look at DAC operation.